# merge multiple files based on column id

Tags: linux

Say i have multiple files x1 x2 x3 x4, all with common header (date, time, year, age),, How can I merge them to one singe file "X" in shell scripting

EXAMPLE: File: x1

date time year age 101014 1344 2012 52 111012 1200 2010 49

File:x2

date time year age 140112 1100 2011 54 230113 0500 2005 46

similiary for other files x3 and x4

have to put them altogether like

date time year age 101014 1344 2012 52 111012 1200 2010 49 140112 1100 2011 54 230113 0500 2005 46 and the similar data from x3 and x4

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk to remove the header from all files that match a pattern, then append those files to a new file:

`awk 'FNR > 1' x* >> X`